# Скролл замирает при использовании JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Сделал я прилипающий к верху страницы блок, все прекрасно работает, но есть одна сильно раздражающая вещь, когда скроллишь страницу, происходит отказ скроллинга полный. Происходит это в непонятных обстоятельствах. Проверил на 10 раз, если отключить собственно скрипт прилипания, то скролл работает замечательно.
Думал, может я что-то не так написал, попробовал 2 sticky плагина, и что странно, там та же проблема, но реже, я не понимаю с чем это вообще связано, может кто разбирается?

P.S. Приведен пример скролла именно девайсом (трекпадом и мышкой), если двигать ползунок, то такой проблемы не наблюдается.

Код моего скрипта:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    var func = $('body').find('.tool_functions'),
    content = $('body').find('.tool_content');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 139) {
        func.addClass('scrolled');
        content.css('margin-top', func.outerHeight() + 10)
    } else {
        func.removeClass('scrolled');
        content.css('margin-top', 0)
    }
});
```

Comment: Приведите хотя бы код того, что вы делаете, текст ошибки в консоли, если такой имеется. Из вашего вопроса не понятно в чем может быть причина.

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin, готово, добавил код, ошибок нет

Comment: Еще заметил что "заморозка" происходит обычно во время смены состояния блока.

Comment: Просто кода мало, необходим минимальный воспроизводимый пример, чтобы можно было посмотреть как это все работает и в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var func = $('body').find('.tool_functions'),
      content = $('body').find('.tool_content');
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 139) {
          func.addClass('scrolled');
          content.css('margin-top', func.outerHeight() + 10)
      } else {
          func.removeClass('scrolled');
          content.css('margin-top', 0)
      }
    }, 4);
});
```

Попробуйте так. Возможно, браузер не успевает обрабатывать событие скрола, т.к. оно срабатывает слишком часто. :)